# Laravel session doesn't start only on index(landing) page

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have  a form on the index page. When I freshly visit the page(Clearing all cookies) the session cookie on the browser is not set. It happens only with the index page. The error thrown is of token mismatch.

**Note**- I have the form token code in the form and the error thrown is due to the session.

Any solution for this? Thanks

Route

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'RootController@getIndex','as'=>'index'));

Route::group(array('before'=>'guest'),function(){
    Route::get('/account/create', array('uses' => 'AccountController@getCreate', 'as' => 'account_create' ));
    Route::get('/account/activate/{activation_code}', array('uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate', 'as' => 'account_activate' ));
    Route::get('/account/login', array('uses' => 'AccountController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login' ));
    Route::get('/account/forgot_password', array('uses' => 'AccountController@getForgotPassword', 'as' => 'forgot_password' ));
    Route::get('/account/recover/{activation_code}', array('uses' => 'AccountController@getRecover', 'as' => 'recover_account' ));

/*
CSRF Protection Group
*/
Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function(){
    Route::post('/account/create', array('uses' => 'AccountController@postCreate'));
    Route::post('/account/login', array('uses' => 'AccountController@postLogin'));
    Route::post('/account/forgot_password', array('uses' => 'AccountController@postForgotPassword'));
    });

});
```

View

```
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'AccountController@postLogin','id'=>'sign-loginform','role'=>'form','class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}

{{ Form::token() }}

<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">                                        
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
   <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
</div>


<div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
       <button id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
       <a id="btn-fblogin" href="{{ URL::route('account_create') }}" class="btn btn-success">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>


{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller

```
public function getIndex(){
    return View::make('root.index')
        ->with('page','index');
}`
```

Comment: could you show us some code?

Comment: What is your session driver ?

Comment: database. I tried the file too. Neither worked

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because:

```
{{Form::open()}}
```

creates form's opening tag, action, method and form's attributes but also adds a hidden token field right after the opening tag closes.

```
{{Form::token()}}
```

only creates the hidden token input field.

So guess what, you create csrf token twice.